# Multiperspective (polyperspective) Usage

Tags: word-usage

Is the word multiperspectively (sometimes polyperspectively) only used to describe literature,  as in narrative perspectives?

Could I use it to describe a personal trait? For example:

> In debates people despise that I multiperspectively argue....

I did see a post asking what the word was for "seeing from multiple points of view" and this word didn't come up.

Also, I understand this is a serious English site, my question is not for any scholarly reason.  I am trying to write to a person and I got stuck while trying to find an adverb that means this.

Comment: I think "from/with multiple/many/different points of view" or something along those lines would be the usual way to express it. "Multiperspectively" is not commonly used, although I can see no reason why it would be incorrect; ultimately this seems to be largely a matter of opinion about what sounds normal or odd.

Comment: Onelook [doesn't list any dictionaries](https://onelook.com/?w=Multiperspectively&ls=a) with "multiperspectively" and [only Wiktionary](https://onelook.com/?w=Multiperspective&ls=a) with "multiperspective". I think that that's a good indication of its rarity.

Comment: standard adverbial: argue from multiple perspectives. I'd avoid the neologistic adverb.

Answer (score 1):

It's highly doubtful 'multiperspectively/ polyperspectively' is used even to describe literature, as in narrative perspectives and either way, it would always look at best obscure.

Many English speakers might make out the meaning but most would be uncomfortable using it themselves, and not only because it seems ambiguous. Does it mean 'from multiple perspectives at once…' or 'from multiple perspectives at different times…' or something else?

If you were going to use that term, '… argue multiperspectively' would sound more natural.

Almost separately, people can never 'despise that I…', though they might '…despise me because I argue…' or '…despise me for arguing…' or even '…despise the fact that I argue…'

Taken together, can you not substitute whatever you hope it means, then play with multimeaningful synonyms?